# Expecting an equals sign, found ':' at line 28 column 19

Tags: apex, visualforce

Im trying to create a two lists in vf page from the key and values of a map, if i select a key from one list,then the other list should populate the values of that key..Below is the apex class and VF page for the same. Im facing error in this code,could you please help me put..please suggest if we have any other sotions also.Please excuse for bad code indenting...
Apex Class

```
public class mapdepend {
public string mycity {get;set;}
map<string,List<string>> mybranches= new map<string,List<string>>();
public list<selectoption> city{get;set;}
public list<selectoption> branch{get;set;}
  public mapdepend(){
    list<string> hyd = new list<string>();
    hyd.add('SR Nagar');
    hyd.add('LB Nagar');
    List<string>  bang=  new list<string>();
    bang.add('Ecity');
    bang.add('Matahalli');
    mybranches.put('hyd',hyd);
    mybranches.put('bang',bang);
    set<string> keys= mybranches.keyset();
    city=new list<selectoption>();
    branch=new list<selectoption>();
    List<string> my = new list<string>();
    my.add('None');
     for(string a: keys)
      {
        selectoption op1= new selectoption(a,a);
        city.add(op1);
      }
      }
   public pagereference show() 
       {
       for (mycity : mybranches.keyset())
           { 
           branch.add(mybranches.get(mycity));
           }
       return null;
       }
    }
```

VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="mapdepend">
<apex:form >
 <apex:selectlist value="{!mycity}" size="1"> 
 <apex:selectoptions value="{!city}">
 </apex:selectoptions>
 <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!show}" rerender="one"/>
 </apex:selectlist>
 <apex:selectList size="1"  id="one">
 <apex:selectOptions value="{!branch}"></apex:selectOptions>
 </apex:selectList>
</apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
for (mycity : mybranches.keyset())
```

you are not providing the data type of `mycity` variable. So change that line to

```
for (String mycity : mybranches.keyset())
```

**EDIT:**

Although the suggested solution may solve your current error, you will run into some other errors.

`branch` is `list<SelectOption>` so you cannot do `branch.add(mybranches.get(mycity));` because you're trying to add `list<String>` to `list<SelectOption>`.

Replace

`branch.add(mybranches.get(mycity));`

with

```
for(String branchString : mybranches.get(mycity)){
    branch.add(new SelectOption(branchString,branchString);
}
```

Comment: @Vignesh- I have given datatype and executed the code..  Incompatible element type List<String> for collection of System.SelectOption at line 30 column 12  error occured

Comment: Take a look at my updated code.

Comment: Logic im looking for: I need to get the list of values associated for a single key in map and store the same list in another list(list<selectoption>)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't declaring what you are iterating through.

Just above the error, you are using another for loop where you are declaring what to iterate through:

```
for(string a: keys)
  {
    selectoption op1= new selectoption(a,a);
    city.add(op1);
  }
```

Here you are stating, for every item in `Keys` create a string variable called `a` and do the followin code.

```
for (mycity : mybranches.keyset())
   { 
   branch.add(mybranches.get(mycity));
   }
```

Try declaring the `mycity` variable as the same type of information in your `mybranches.keyset()`:

```
for (string mycity : mybranches.keyset())
   { 
   branch.add(mybranches.get(mycity));
   }
```

Comment: @Zainogj-Thanks for pointing at variable declaration